Movie where a young director's student film gets made (badly) by a major studio
I have a vivid memory of a 1980s style film (which I likely viewed in the 1980s or early 1990s) where a young, upcoming director, who looked like a young Patrick Dempsey, is approached by a major studio after the success of his student film; a stark Bergman-esque black-and-white silent drama about three impoverished spinster sisters living in a shack in the wastes of Siberia.
He is initially pensive about the project, but is repeatedly re-assured by the studio execs that they will remain true to his vision.  He agrees and signs a contract.
He is excited about getting started and overawed at the size and scope of the studio and his salary as director, but progressive planning meetings cause him more and more concern. First the studio insist on changing the film to colour, arguing that audiences won't watch a black-and-white film. Then they make the three sisters a lot younger and prettier. Then they change the setting from the wintry Steppe, to Southern California. At each stage he has misgivings about the changes, but is convinced by the execs that this is needed to ensure the success of his project, or that these are actually quite small changes that will help the audience relate better to the key themes.
His final humiliation comes at the premiere, where the studio reveal that they've renamed the film in order to take advantage of the success of another recent film series. In the final scene we see the opening credits, or possibly a movie poster. He's been swallowed up by the Hollywood 'system' and his serious, thoughtful film has morphed into...

"Bikini Party Summer IV"

or something similarly dumb-sounding.

Note. Not Sweet Liberty, although the themes are somewhat similar.

The Big Picture (1989) with Kevin Bacon matches in concept albeit that the specifics of the plot do not precisely match the question.

Film student and aspiring writer/director Nick Chapman, an Ohio native, finds himself the winner of a prestigious student film contest in LA. Overnight, Hollywood VIPs want to make deals with Nick. He settles on a quirky agent (Martin Short) to represent him and signs a deal with a major film studio to make his dream movie.
Nick finds the Hollywood studio "process" distasteful and is forced to make many creative compromises like adding a pop music soundtrack and aging down the middle-aged characters to college age.

The whole thing is on YouTube




I think I did pretty well, given that I've apparently suffered multiple concussions in the intervening 30-ish years since I saw this

ha, nice one! funnily enough, I wonder how this is going to go: https://www.dazeddigital.com/film-tv/article/58138/1/a24-backrooms-creepypasta-horror-directed-17-year-old-filmmaker-kane-pixels
